# how to generate test data for a postgres table , where in that table their are two columns which have UUID data type?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have below table with schema , i want to generate some 10K or 20K test data and i want the test data values as per related column data type , anyone can you please suggest on this , in this table i want the test data for ID unique values for each row , but am fine with migration_id values can be same for more than one row

`CREATE TABLE student_services ( id uuid NOT NULL, mobile_type VARCHAR(10) NOT null, migration_id uuid NOT NULL, service_type text NOT NULL, s_config jsonb NOT NULL, subs_id uuid NULL, expire_at timestamp NOT NULL );`

i tried with some scripts but am failing to handle UUID type

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you plan to use any framework / library to generate the data?

Answer (score 0):

the UUID values can be generated by using the uuid extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

and then you can simply generate the UUID using the function

```
uuid_generate_v4();
```

For rest of the data you can generate using any external program in java/node/python or import it from an excel/csv

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PostgreSQL 13 or above, you can use [`gen_random_uuid()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html) to generate random UUIDs.

For older version, you would need to use the [`uuid-ossp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) extension, as described in @vaibhav's answer. The downside is that `CREATE EXTENSION ...` needs to be done as a database superuser first.

Comment: is this generated random UUID always unique , i mean will it always generate unique UUID ?

Comment: @Bravo it's a random UUID (UUID v4). Randomness is of course dependent on the quality of the PRNG, but AFAIK, this relies on `pg_strong_random` internally, so it should be good enough (especially if it's just for test data)